# Filter one RDD based on keys in another

Tags: scala, filter, apache-spark

I have two RDDs:

```
**rdd1**
id1 val1
id2 val2

**rdd2**
id1 v1
id2 v2
id1 v3
id8 v7
id1 v4
id3 v5
id6 v6
```

I want to filter RDD2 such that it contains keys of rdd1 only. So the output will be

```
**output**
id1 v1
id2 v2
id1 v3
id1 v4
```

This has been asked in stackoverflow before but for a smaller dataset where people broadcasted set and then used to filter, but my problem is rdd1 size is > 500 million, and rdd2 is more than 10 billion

Pls help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use join:

```
val res: RDD[(Long, V)] = rdd1.join(rdd2)
                              .map { case(k, (_, v2)) => (k, v2) }
```